# python pandas substring based on columns values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, substring

Given the following df:

```
data = {'Description':  ['with lemon', 'lemon', 'and orange', 'orange'],
        'Start': ['6', '1', '5', '1'],
       'Length': ['5', '5', '6', '6']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print (df)
```

I would like to substring the "Description" based on what is specified in the other columns as start and length, here the expected output:

```
data = {'Description':  ['with lemon', 'lemon', 'and orange', 'orange'],
        'Start': ['6', '1', '5', '1'],
       'Length': ['5', '5', '6', '6'],
       'Res':  ['lemon', 'lemon', 'orange', 'orange']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print (df)
```

Is there a way to make it dynamic or another compact way?

```
df['Res'] = df['Description'].str[1:2]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to loop, a list comprehension will be the most efficient (python ≥3.8 due to the walrus operator, thanks @I'mahdi):

```
df['Res'] = [s[(start:=int(a)-1):start+int(b)] for (s,a,b)
             in zip(df['Description'], df['Start'], df['Length'])]
```

Or using pandas for the conversion (thanks @DaniMesejo):

```
df['Res'] = [s[a:a+b] for (s,a,b) in 
             zip(df['Description'],
                 df['Start'].astype(int)-1,
                 df['Length'].astype(int))]
```

output:

```
  Description Start Length     Res
0  with lemon     6      5   lemon
1       lemon     1      5   lemon
2  and orange     5      6  orange
3      orange     1      6  orange
```

##### handling non-integers / NAs

```
df['Res'] = [s[a:a+b] if pd.notna(a) and pd.notna(b) else 'NA'
             for (s,a,b) in 
             zip(df['Description'],
                 pd.to_numeric(df['Start'], errors='coerce').convert_dtypes()-1,
                 pd.to_numeric(df['Length'], errors='coerce').convert_dtypes()
                )]
```

output:

```
    Description Start Length     Res
0    with lemon     6      5   lemon
1         lemon     1      5   lemon
2    and orange     5      6  orange
3        orange     1      6  orange
4  pinapple xxx    NA     NA      NA
5      orangiie    NA     NA      NA
```

Comment: `python.version` >=  `3.8`

Comment: I think is better if you sum start + length at pandas level and then iterate, right?

Comment: @I'mahdi Correct, for python < 3.8 use a function or duplicate the convertion  of `a` to int ;)

Comment: @Dani also true, I added a variant ;)

Comment: what about if in some case the Start is NA? How can I skip it?

Comment: @highbury depends what you want to do, you can add a test and return the original string, or fillna with start=0 and length=len, or dropna

Comment: @mozway how to add a test?

Comment: Can you update your input/output example?

Comment: input: data = {'Description':  ['with lemon', 'lemon', 'and orange', 'orange', 'pinapple xxx', 'orangiie'],
        'Start': ['6', '1', '5', '1', 'NA', 'NA'],
       'Length': ['5', '5', '6', '6', 'NA', 'NA']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print (df)

Comment: output: data = {'Description':  ['with lemon', 'lemon', 'and orange', 'orange', 'pinapple xxx', 'orangiie'],
        'Start': ['6', '1', '5', '1', 'NA', 'NA'],
       'Length': ['5', '5', '6', '6', 'NA', 'NA'],
       'Res':  ['lemon', 'lemon', 'orange', 'orange', 'NA', 'NA']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print (df)

Answer (score 0):

Given that the fruit name of interest always seems to be the final word in the description column, you might be able to use a regex extract approach here.

```py
data["Res"] = data["Description"].str.extract(r'(\w+)$')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.map`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/map) to cycle through the Series. Use `split(' ')` to separate the words if there is space and get the last word in the list `[-1]`.

```py
df['RES'] = df['Description'].map(lambda x: x.split(' ')[-1])
```